# can kears support reading files from hdfs?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, hdfs

Because there are much large data large data are genereated on hdfs.Can keras support reading hdfs file directly?Previous i put large data to local disk,and read open,but it cost time and storage

I tried to put hdfs files to local disks,but it cost time.

```
def generator_array_from_file(path,word2ID):
    X1 = np.zeros((batch_size, text1_maxlen), dtype=np.int32)
    X1_len = np.zeros((batch_size,), dtype=np.int32)
    X2 = np.zeros((batch_size, text2_maxlen), dtype=np.int32)
    X2_len = np.zeros((batch_size,), dtype=np.int32)
    Y = np.zeros((batch_size, class_num), dtype=np.int32)
    count = 0
    while True:
        fts=codecs.open(path, 'r', "utf-8")
        for line in fts:

train_generator = generator_array_from_file(train_set,wordID)
history = model.fit_generator(train_generator)
```

can read hdfs file directly

Answer (score -2):

Yes, for this there is the `HDF5Matrix` class, described [here](https://keras.io/io_utils/), which simulated a numpy array interface on top of an HDF5 file, you just need to make instances of this class using the hdf5 filename and the dataset inside that file:

```
from keras.utils import HDF5Matrix

X = HDF5Matrix('file.hdf5', 'data')
y = HDF5Matrix('file.hdf5', 'labels')

model.fit(x, y, epochs=..., batch_size=...)
```